# How to read a snippet from a file using groovy?

Tags: groovy, filereader

I am reading a file in groovy using this simple sample code

```
file.eachLine {line->
 // do something with line
}
```

For example my file has some data like this

```
blah blah blah 
This is some more lines
more lines
Insert into something
(x1,x2,x3)
(Select * from
some table
where 
something = something)
on rowid = something;
```

So I want to read a snippet. 
If I see a line with rowid that also has a 'semicolon' at the end. then I want to read back till '(select'

So after reading this file I want to have a string that contains:

```
(Select * from
    some table
    where 
    something = something)
    on rowid = something;
```

Is that possible? and how?

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of your file is small, it's easy enough to read the file in it's entire and then use a bit of regex to get the part(s) you want:

```
def file = new File('/home/bart/Temp/test.txt')
def contents = file.getText()
def matcher = contents =~ /\(Select[^)]++\)\s++.*?rowid\s=\s.*;/
matcher.each { println it }
```

Produces:

```
(Select * from
some table
where 
something = something)
on rowid = something;
```

Comment: thanks! that regex seems interesting but it is not working for me. in your test.txt file do you have the data in seperate lines or all in one line?

Comment: @Drake: they're all on separate lines. When the input is a string without line breaks, it still works (output: '(Select * from some table where  something = something) on rowid = something;').
For the records: I'm using Groovy 1.6

Comment: ... but if no line breaks are present in the input file, I would change my regex slightly: no greedy DOT-STARS in that case!

Answer (score 0):

Collect the lines in a list and when you notice the ";", stop the implicit loop by throwing an exception.

The result you seek is the sublist from `list.lastIndexOf('(select')` to the end of the list.

Comment: list doesnt have 'lastIndexOf' method

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html I couldnt find it in the API. do you have a link where its shown in an example?

Comment: Odd. It's mentioned in the docs (http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections) and as fixed in GROOVY-1007 (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1007)